# Convenient way to decode nested JSON object in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

Let's say you have some JSON:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "errormessage": "Could not get user with ID: -1.",
        "errorcode": 14
    }
}
```

For a given Error struct:

```
struct APIError: Decodable {
    let code: Int?
    let message: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "errorcode"
        case message = "errormessage"
    }
}
```

Hit the web service, get the JSON, and initialize the struct:

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)
{ (data, response, error) in
    // Doesn't work because the portion of the JSON we want is in the "data" key
    let e = try? JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
}
task.resume()
```

Is there some easy way to do something like `data["data"]`? What's the correct model to follow?

**Solution A** - Convert the data to a JSON object, get the object we want, then convert it to a Data object and decode.

```
let jsonFull = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any]
let json = jsonFull["data"]
let data_error = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
let e = try? JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data_error)
```

**Solution B** - Wrap the target item in another struct

```
struct temp : Decodable {
    let status: String?
    let data: APIError?
}

let e = try? JSONDecoder().decode(temp.self, from: data).data
```

**Solution C** - Set the nested structure in decode (what if it is several objects deep?)

```
let e = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Any, APIError.self], from: data)
```

What patterns am I missing? What's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Solution C does not work (`Any` is not supported). There is a solution D using `nestedContainers`, but in this case solution B is the usual one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
struct APIError: Decodable {
    let code: Int
    let message: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    enum ErrorCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "errorcode"
        case message = "errormessage"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ErrorCodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)

        code = try nestedContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code)
        message = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["status": "error", "data": ["errorcode": 14, "errormessage": "Could not get user with ID: -1."]], options: [])
let error = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
```

Comment: That seems really sensitive. What happens if you want to decode an APIError in another part of the API? For example, maybe the API is messy, and in certain endpoints it's `["status": "error", "body": ["errorcode": 14, "errormessage": "Could not get user with ID: -1."]]` instead.

Comment: The solution B will not work in this case as well. And what if in another part of API it will be not `errorcode` and `errormessage`, but `error` and `message`? So, in this case only manual parsing (solution A) is appropriate.

Comment: I was thinking about writing an extension for conveniently grabbing key paths from Data. Are there any reasons this isn't a popular solution? Why wouldn't Apple have provided an easier way to deal with key paths?

Comment: I once wrote such extension. You can see it here: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a68cc9a4b3a155f556c998d